How can I move gitlabci vault integration as transversal template/reference/whatever?
I have the following working example in my gitlab-ci.yml file
variables:
  VAULT_SERVER_URL: https://my-vault.com
  VAULT_NAMESPACE: my-namespace  # Vault EE Only
  VAULT_AUTH_PATH: jwt
  VAULT_AUTH_ROLE: gitlab-ci

vault_test:
  id_tokens:
    VAULT_ID_TOKEN:
      aud: $VAULT_SERVER_URL
  secrets:
    TEST_HELLO:
      vault:
        engine: 
          name: kv-v2
          path: gitlab-ci
        path: test
        field: hello
      file: false
  script:
    - echo $TEST_HELLO

As I have many gitlab-ci.yml files across my repositories that all needs secrets from vault.
I'd like to factorize the above example inside a template or reference.
The target would be something like :
# /cicd/templates/vault/secrets.yaml
variables:
  VAULT_SERVER_URL: https://my-vault.com
  VAULT_NAMESPACE: my-namespace  # Vault EE Only
  VAULT_AUTH_PATH: jwt
  VAULT_AUTH_ROLE: gitlab-ci

get_secret:
  id_tokens:
    VAULT_ID_TOKEN:
      aud: $VAULT_SERVER_URL
  secrets:
    TEST_HELLO:
      vault:
        engine: 
          name: kv-v2
          path: gitlab-ci
        path: test
        field: hello
      file: false

# /one-repository/gitlab.yml
include: 
  - project: 'cicd/templates' 
    file: '/vault/secrets.yaml'

build:
  ## use here the reference with args to retrieve any specific secret from vault
  ## secrets: !reference [.get_secret, path: test, field: hello]
  ## SOMETHING THAT WORKS
  script:
    - echo $TEST_HELLO

I don't know if what I imagine if doable with yaml files.
Do you have any idea or example to do so ?

This can be done via extends and variables:
# /cicd/templates/vault/secrets.yaml
variables:
  VAULT_SERVER_URL: https://my-vault.com
  VAULT_NAMESPACE: my-namespace  # Vault EE Only
  VAULT_AUTH_PATH: jwt
  VAULT_AUTH_ROLE: gitlab-ci

.get_secret:
  id_tokens:
    VAULT_ID_TOKEN:
      aud: $VAULT_SERVER_URL
  secrets:
    TEST_HELLO:
      vault:
        engine: 
          name: kv-v2
          path: $ENGINE
        path: $MYPATH
        field: $FIELD
      file: false

and then
# /one-repository/gitlab.yml
include: 
  - project: 'cicd/templates' 
    file: '/vault/secrets.yaml'

build:
  extends: .get_secret
  script:
    - echo $TEST_HELLO
  variables:
    ENGINE: gitlab-ci
    MYPATH: test
    FIELD: hello
     

Note that PATH is already a variable in Gitlab-CI, so I have used MYPATH.
